# Finding the selected item in an ItemsControl when the PreviewMouseLeftButtonDownCommand RelayCommand\EventToCommand fires

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, eventtocommand

My app is wpf mvvm, using RelayCommand\EventToCommand bindings for the events. My app does some typical drag & drop from a ListBox onto an ItemsControl (it is actually an image control with an ItemsControl on top, that is holding the dropped items). The ListBox is populated with a vm ObservableCollection. And the ItemsControl is also an ObservableCollection that I insert the dropped MyObj items into.

When I drag items from the ListBox and drop them in to\on to the ItemsControl\image it all works fine. In the PreviewMouseLeftButtonDownCommand I use the System.Windows.Media.VisualTreeHelper to recursively walk up the visual tree, so when I drag from the ListBox I can find the MyObj item that is being dragged. But when I try drag an item from the ItemsControl the code does not work. All I can get back is the DataTemplate conversion of the item (a lable). So my question is; how do I get the selected item from my ItemsControl when the PreviewMouseLeftButtonDownCommand RelayCommand\EventToCommand fires?

the vm C#:

```
PreviewMouseLeftButtonDownCommand = new RelayCommand<MouseButtonEventArgs>(e =>
{
    if (e.Source is ListBox)
    {
    // get dragged list box item
    ListBox listBox = e.Source as ListBox;
    ListBoxItem listBoxItem = VisualHelper.FindAncestor<ListBoxItem>((DependencyObject)e.OriginalSource);

    // Find the data behind the listBoxItem
    if (listBox == null || listBoxItem == null) return;

    MyObj tag = (MyObj)listBox.ItemContainerGenerator.ItemFromContainer(listBoxItem);

     // Initialize the drag & drop operation
    DataObject dragData = new DataObject("myObj", tag);
    DragDrop.DoDragDrop(listBoxItem, dragData, DragDropEffects.Move);
}
else if (e.Source is ItemsControl)
{
    ItemsControl itemsControl = e.Source as ItemsControl;
    object item = VisualHelper.FindAncestor<UIElement>((DependencyObject)e.OriginalSource);

    if (itemsControl == null || item == null) return;

    MyObj tag = (MyObj)itemsControl.ItemContainerGenerator.ItemFromContainer(item);


    // Initialize the drag & drop operation
    DataObject dragData = new DataObject("myObj", tagDragging);
    DragDrop.DoDragDrop(item, dragData, DragDropEffects.Move);
    }
});
```

Comment: P.S. I read a related post about using the point of the mouse click to find the item. I did get it working using this but it seems like a hak so I am looking for another suggestion.

Comment: ItemsControl has no concept of a SelectedItem.  So you would have to use the location of the Mouse during the left button click.  

Can you use a templated ListBox instead of ItemsControl?

Comment: If there is a way to allow the user to drop the item anywhere on the list box and for the list box to allow the dropped item to render at that location, then yes this would be a viable solution. When I tried this the list box keeps creating a list of items and did not allow the placement of the item from a point (x & y co-ord). Any ideas on how to change\customise how the list box (or any other ItemsControl derived control) renders it's items?

Comment: I think it may be your lucky day.  I just ran into this last week.  See this post and see if it may help:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6961963/wpf-listbox-indexfrompoint

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the code I've used in the past:

```
private void DragSource_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    // Get ItemsControl for object being dragged
    if (sender is ItemsControl)
        _sourceItemsControl = sender as ItemsControl;
    else if (sender is Panel)
        _sourceItemsControl = WPFHelpers.FindAncester<ItemsControl>(sender as Panel);

    // Get ItemContainer for object being dragged
    FrameworkElement sourceItemsContainer = _sourceItemsControl
        .ContainerFromElement((Visual)e.OriginalSource) as FrameworkElement;

    // Get data object for object being dragged
    if (sourceItemsContainer == null)
        _draggedObject = _sourceItemsControl.DataContext;
    else if (sourceItemsContainer == e.Source)
        _draggedObject = e.Source;
    else
        _draggedObject = sourceItemsContainer.DataContext;

}
```

WPF Helper class

```
public class WPFHelpers
{
    public static T FindAncester<T>(DependencyObject current)
    where T : DependencyObject
    {
        current = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(current);

        while (current != null)
        {
            if (current is T)
            {
                return (T)current;
            }
            current = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(current);
        };
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: I believe you have a typo: you use "sourceObjectContainer" and "sourceObjectContainer" to refer to the same object.

Comment: @Mick Thanks, its been updated. And you have a typo in your typo correction :) Took me a minute to understand you were referring to `sourceItemsContainer` and `sourceObjectContainer`